# A formula is satisfiable under $I \iff |I|=1$?

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, model-theory, satisfiability

> Let $A(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ be a formula with no quantifiers and no function symbols.
> Prove that $∀x_1 · · · ∀x_nA(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ is satisfiable if and only if it is satisfiable in an
> interpretation whose domain has only one element.

Attempt:

$\leftarrow$ It follows by hypothesis.

$\to$ Suppose $∀x_1 · · · ∀x_nA(x_1, . . . , x_n)=S$ is satisfiable.

$\implies $ There exists an interpretation $I$ such that $S^I=true$

in other words there is a model for $S$

$\implies$ There exists a Herbrand model for $S$.

By hypothesis $A(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ is a formula with no quantifiers and no function symbols, hence the domain of $I$ must consist only of constants.

---

I am stuck here.

What can I do from here?

How to prove that the domain must consist of only one constant $c$?

Help me please

---

**Edit** Although this exercise is from Logic for computer science book by Mordechai it's expected to do the proof with 'similar' notation and conventions used in Introduction to mathematical logic by Mendelson, for instance an  *interpretation I* looks like: $I=\begin{cases} D=\mathbb N \\ a^I=2\\ f^I(x)=x^2\\ P^I(x)="x\ is\ even" \end{cases}$

as you can see there is no relations, just a domain,constants,functions and predicates.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why? Why another different constants other that $a$ can't exists in the formula?

Comment: As noted by Alex, we have to assume that there are no constants in the formula. See page 168: "Constant symbols are no longer needed since they are the same as $0$-ary functions."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do you know if Logic for computer science book by Mordechai has a Solution manual?

Comment: Sorry... I do not know. Try [here](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/sci-tea/benari/research-activities/mathematical-logic-computer-science-third-edition : "On the book's website there is also a link where instructors can obtain the solution manual".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per answer above, we have to assume that there are no *constant* symbols in the formula.

See [Mordechai Ben-Ari](https://books.google.it/books?id=TQ1n03kEBOkC&printsec=frontcover), page 168 :

> Constant symbols are no longer needed since they are the same as $0$-ary functions.

See page 177 : let assume that $S$ is the set of clauses corresponding to the formula $\mathcal A$ :

> let $H_S$, the *Herbrand universe* of $S$ [...] If there are no constant symbols or $0$-ary function symbols in $S$, initialize the inductive definition of $H_S$ with an arbitrary constant symbol $a$.
>
> The Herbrand universe is just the set of ground terms that can be formed from
> symbols in $S$.

Due to the lack of *function* symbols, we have $H_S = \{ a \}$.

See page 178:

> Let $H_S$ be the Herbrand universe for $S$. $B_S$, the *Herbrand base* for
> $S$, is the set of ground atomic formulas that can be formed from predicate symbols in $S$ and terms in $H_S$.

But $a$ is the only term in $H_S$; thus, if e.g. $p_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n),\ldots, p_m(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ are the *predicate* symbols occurring in $\mathcal A$, the Herbrand base will be:

> $B_S = \{ p_1(a,\ldots,a),\ldots, p_m(a,\ldots, a) \}$.

An *Herbrand interpretation* for $S$ can be defined by giving the subset of the Herbrand base where the relations $R_1,\ldots, R_m$, i.e. the interpretations of the corresponding predicates, hold.

Now we can apply [page 179] :

> **Theorem 9.24** A set of clauses $S$ has a model iff it has an Herbrand model.

We know that $S$ [the set of clauses corresponding to the formula $\forall x_i \ \mathcal A$] is *satisfiable*; thus, it has a model and so also an Herbrand model, i.e. an interpretation $\mathcal H$ with domain the Herbrand universe $H_S = \{ a \}$, such that:

> > $\mathcal H \vDash S$.

---

We can follow the "instructions" of Alex's answer to manufacture the Herbrand interpretation based on the above Herbrand base.

Basically, we may describe Alex's inductive construction of the interpretation this way: $A(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ may be expressed equivalently a a set of *clauses*, i.e. as disjunctions of predicates $p_i$ and their negation.

Consider the simple example $p_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \lor \lnot p_m(x_1,\ldots, x_m)$. We know that it is satisfiable: thus either $p_1(a,\ldots,a)$ holds or $\lnot p_m(a,\ldots, a)$ holds.

In the first case, we have to assume that the interpretation of $p_1$ is satisfied by $(a,\ldots,a)$, i.e. $(a,\ldots,a) \in R_1$, while in the second case we have to assume that $(a,\ldots,a) \notin R_m$.

And so on. The satisfiability of the original formula guarantee that this procedure will succeed.

Comment: So this side $\to$ of the proof starts after Theorem 9.24 right? And actually easier than this side $\leftarrow$.

Comment: I don't understand Alex's instructions to manufacture the Herbrand interpretation (his notation is scary..), Can't I just write _We now consider the Herbrand interpretation $I_H$ for $S$ as the subset of the Herbrand base where the interpretations of the corresponding predicates hold_ ?

Answer (score 4):

If there is more than one constant symbol in the language, then this is not true. For example if $c$ and $d$ are constant symbols, then $A$ could be the sentence (with no free variables) $\lnot (c = d)$, which is satisfiable, but only in a structure of size at least $2$.

Sometimes, constant symbols are viewed as special kinds of function symbols (of arity $0$), so the hypothesis "no function symbols" might include "no constant symbols". In this case (also assuming the usual convention that all structures are nonempty), the statement is true.

Indeed, suppose $\forall \overline{x}\, A(\overline{x})$ is satisfiable in a structure $M$. Since $M$ is nonempty, there is some $n\in M$. Let $N$ be the substructure of $M$ with domain $\{n\}$ (so if $R$ is a relation in the language, then $R(n,\dots,n)$ holds in $N$ if and only if $R(n,\dots,n)$ holds in $M$). Now $M\models \forall \overline{x},A(\overline{x})$, so in particular $M\models A(n,\dots,n)$, which implies that $N\models A(n,\dots,n)$ (since $A$ is quantifier-free), and hence $N\models \forall \overline{x}\, A(\overline{x})$ (since the universal quantifiers just range over the single element $n$ in the domain of $N$).

In the case that there is a single constant symbol $c$ in the language, we can use the same proof, but pick $n$ to be the interpretation of $c$ in $M$. This fails is there are more constant symbols (or if there are function symbols), since then the singleton $\{n\}$ might not be the domain of a substructure, since it might not contain the interpretations of all the constant symbols or be closed under the interpretations of all the function symbols.

Finally, I'll just note that the proof I gave above is a special case of the (also quite easy) proof that "universal sentences go down": If $\varphi$ is a universal sentence (of the form $\forall \overline{x}\,\psi(\overline{x})$ where $\psi$ is quantifier-free), and $N$ is a substructure of $M$, then $M\models \varphi\implies N\models \varphi$.

---

**Edit:** Let me try to rewrite the argument in a way that matches your terminology. We have a formula $A(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with no quantifiers and no function or constant symbols. Let's say it contains the predicate symbols $\{p_1,\dots,p_m\}$, where $p_i$ has arity $n_i$. If the closed formula $B: \forall x_1\cdots\forall x_n A(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is satisfiable, then there is an interpretation $\mathscr{I} = (D,\{R_1,\dots,R_m\})$ such that $v_{\mathscr{I}}(B) = T$.

Pick any element $a\in D$. We'll define a new interpretation $\mathscr{I}' = (\{a\},\{R_1',\dots,R_m'\})$ whose domain has only the single element $a$. To do this, we have to specify the $n_i$-ary relation $R_i'$ on $\{a\}$ for all $i$. Now an $n_i$-ary relation on $\{a\}$ is a subset of $\{a\}^{n_i} = \{(a,\dots,a)\}$, so it is either $\{(a,\dots,a)\}$ or $\emptyset$. We define $R_i'$ to be $\{(a,\dots,a)\}$ if $(a,\dots,a)\in R_i$ and $\emptyset$ if $(a,\dots,a)\notin R_i$.

Now since $v_{\mathscr{I}}(B) = T$, we have that for all $a_1,\dots,a_n\in D$, letting $\sigma\colon \mathcal{V}\to \mathscr{I}$ be the assignment $x_i\mapsto a_i$, $v_\sigma(A) = T$. In particular, taking $a_i = a$ for all $i$, we have $v_\sigma(A) = T$.

Now you need to check by induction on the structure of $A$, starting from the atomic formulas, that letting $\sigma'\colon \mathcal{V}\to \mathscr{I}'$ be the assignment $x_i\mapsto a$ for all $i$, we also have $v_{\sigma'}(A) = T$.

Finally, we find that $v_{\mathscr{I}'}(B) = T$, since the only possible assignment for the universal quantifiers appearing in $B$ is $\sigma'$.

Comment: hmm I am not familiar with the term _structure_, I don't recall my teacher mentioned it, is there another word that might substitute _structure_?

Comment: Which book are you based on? I've to say I don't understand the proof at all :(

Comment: "Interpretation" is an (old-fashioned) synonym for structure. I reserve the word "interpretation" for the interpretations of symbols and variables in a structure (i.e. a structure is a domain together with interpretations of the symbols in the language).

Comment: My notation and terminology is standard in model theory, and it should agree with that in any modern logic book which covers first-order (predicate) logic.

Comment: @Michelle If you can be more precise about what in my answer you don't understand, I can try to help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with definitions of substructure $N$ nor relations like this $R(n,...,n)$, hence I can't understand.  maybe it's because my teacher is using the book Mathematical logic for computer science by Mordechai, so am I.

Comment: Do you know that book?

Comment: I am not familiar with that book, but I looked it up. It seems like the author uses the word "predicate" instead of the word "relation". I'll rewrite the argument using the terminology of that book. Let me know if my edit helps.

Comment: Here $\mathscr{I} = (D,\{R_1,\dots,R_m\})$ the set $\{R_1,\dots ,R_m\}$ means  predicates?

Comment: What's this $a_1,\dots,a_n\in D$? or why it happens?

Comment: I wonder why my professor doesn't use standard terminology..

Comment: Yes, the $R_i$ are the *relations* on $D$ corresponding to the predicates $p_i$ (see Section 7.3 p. 136 of your book). The arbitrary elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in D$ come from the semantics of the universal quantifiers (see Definition 7.19 p. 137 of your book).

Comment: :) I appreciate you help Alex, unfortunately I don't understand the proof. I used to use a logic book by Mendelson an all this definitions of interpretations, models, etc. I've learned from that book. Although  at this moment my teacher is using Mordechai. And believe me it's not easy to understand the def _interpretation_ from Mordechai.