# Idempotent substitution $\theta$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, substitution, idempotents

Exercise:

> A substitution $\theta = \{x_1\leftarrow t_1, \dots, x_n\leftarrow t_n\}$ is idempotent iff $\theta = \theta\theta$. Let $V$ be
>   the set of variables occurring in the terms $\{t_1, \dots, t_n\}$. Prove that $\theta$ is idempotent iff $V \cap \{x_1, \dots , x_n\} = \emptyset$.

Show that the mgu’s produced by the unification algorithm is
idempotent.

**Proof:**

$\leftarrow$

Suppose $\theta$ is idempotent. Then $\theta = \theta\theta$.

Recall that by definition of substitution, for each $t_i$, $t_i\neq x_i; \ i=1,\dots,n$. Hence $V \cap \{x_1, \dots , x_n\} = \emptyset$.

$\rightarrow$

I don't know how this is $\theta\theta$ explicit. I've done composition where both substitutions are different but in this case it's difficult to visualize.

Could somebody please help me? I don't know how to continue.

Comment: @Andrew Li I think the proof was clearer with $\leftarrow$ and $\rightarrow$

Comment: You can add it back if you prefer.

Comment: Intuitively, with subst $\theta$ we put $t_i$ in place of $x_i$. Thus, after subst, there are no more occurrences of $x_i$... **unless** some $x_i$ occurs in turn into $t_i$, in which case the subst has "generated" new occurrences of $x_i$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but $x_i$ can't occur in $t_i$ by definition of subst. Thus $\theta $ will only consist of $t_i's$. Isn't it?

Comment: If the $x_i$'s do not occur into the $t_j$'s, then $x_i \notin V$ "by def", so $V \cap \{ x_i \}= \emptyset$ always ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA well.. that doesn't makes sense then. By definition $x_i\neq t_i$ but then what can happen indeed is $x_i=t_j$ for $i\neq j$, yes that must be correct. Am I right?

Comment: You say that $x_i \ne t_i$; but what about $x_i$ and $t_j$ ? And what about $x_i=u$ and $t_j=u + 2v$ ?

Comment: See example page 188: $θ = \{ x←f (y), y←f (a), z←u \}$; as you can see $y$ is replaced by $f(a)$ but it is re-introduced by $f(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\theta$ is *idempotent*.

Intuitively, with substitution $θ$ we put the *term* $t_i$ in place of every occurrence of $x_i$.

Thus, after substitution, there are no more occurrences of $x_i$, unless some $x_i$ occurs in turn into some $t_j$, in which case the substitution has generated new occurrences of $x_i$.

But idempotency means that the second application of the substitution $\theta$ has no effect.

The way to formalize it is that:

> $V \cap \{ x_1, \ldots ,x_n \} = \emptyset$,

where $V$ is the set of variables occurring in the terms $t_j$.

A simple counterexample will show that the condition $V \cap \{ x_1, \ldots ,x_n \} = \emptyset$ is necessary for idempotency.

Consider the substitution:

> $θ = \{ x←f(y), y←f(a), z←u \}$.

We have variables $\{ x,y,z \}$ and $V = \{ y,u \}$; thus: $V \cap \{ x,y,z \} = \{ y \} \ne \emptyset$.

Starting with $\{ x,y,z \}$ and applying $\theta$, we get: $\{ f(y), f(a), u \}$.

Wit a new application of $\theta$ we get: $\{ f(f(a)), f(a), u \}$ and thus $\theta \ne \theta \theta$.

---

Suppose now that $V \cap \{ x_1, \ldots ,x_n \} = \emptyset$.

This means that $\theta$ cannot introduce new occurrences of the $x_i$'s.

Thus, a new "application" of $\theta$ has no effect, i.e. $\theta \theta = \theta$., that means that $\theta$ is *idempotent*.

Comment: I'm slightly confused,  Is  this to prove $\leftarrow$?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: As $\theta$ cannot introduce new occurrences of the $x_i's$, $\theta\theta \theta...=\theta$ also holds?

Comment: @Michelle - yes, of course.

Comment: I supposed it was true, but as I've failed many times I'm a very insecure when it's about math..

Comment: Would you mind to take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711548/a-formula-is-satisfiable-under-i-iff-i-1 again?